# Selectize.js onFocus callback not working

Tags: jquery, onfocus, selectize.js

I have a drop down select box using the jquery Selectize.js plugin.  What I want it to do is not display the drop down selections when tabbing to the field, but still open up the drop down by any other means.

I have set 'openOnFocus: false' to prevent it from opening the drop down when it first gains focus, which works.  But I don't want the user to have to double click if using a mouse.  So I tried setting up the onFocus callback to check if the tab key was pressed, and if not, then give it focus again.  The onFocus doesn't seem to ever fire.  I added Console.log to verify that it isn't.  Any advice?  Is there a better way to go about this?  Thanks!

Here is my code.

```
$("#branch_entry").selectize({      
  hideSelected: true,               
  sortField: "value",               
  openOnFocus: false,
  onFocus: function() {
    console.log("focus");                                      
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code != 9) {    // not tab  
      $("#branch_entry").focus();   
    }                               
  }                                 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to handle the `click` event in the selectize input element and call the `selectize.open()` method.

HTML:

```
<div id="branch_entry-div">
  <select id="branch_entry">
    <option value="0">Item 0</option>
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#branch_entry").selectize({      
  hideSelected: true,               
  sortField: "value",               
  openOnFocus: false
});
$("#branch_entry-div .selectize-input").on('click', function() {
  $("#branch_entry")[0].selectize.open();
});
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tn3oexfb/4/)</kbd>

Comment: Default Selectize open - ur code helped me a lot. Only $("#branch_entry")[0].selectize.open(); But the fiddle isn't working though. Thanks Man